# Serialize object with the property type in xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I want to serialize the following class

```
[Serializable]
public class Model{
    [XmlElement("ElementName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Number")]
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

And I will get the following result:

```
<Model>
  <ElementName>testData</ElementName>
  <Number>5</Number>
</Model>
```

Is there any way xml document to look like that with the property type:

```
<Model>
  <ElementName><string>testData</string></ElementName>
  <Number><int>5</int></Number>
</Model>
```

Comment: probably [xmltocsharp](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) may help you to create desired class for a given XML

Comment: Why would you want that? I've not once *ever* seen xml in that style. But to be explicit: no `XmlSerializer` won't help you output that *unless* you change the model to add a layer of indirection

Comment: note: you do not need `[Serializable]` - that has nothing to do with xml serialization

Comment: The type int is usually added to xml as an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think to get that output *with `XmlSerializer`* would be to change the model to *include those layers*:

```cs
public class XmlInt32
{
    [XmlElement("int")]
    public int Value {get;set;}
    // not shown... maybe some implicit operators?
}
public class XmlString
{
    [XmlElement("string")]
    public string Value {get;set;}
    // not shown... maybe some implicit operators?
}
public class Model
{
    [XmlElement("ElementName")]
    public XmlString Name { get; set; }

    public XmlInt32 Number { get; set; }
}
```

Note, however, that this layout looks pretty unusual and atypical; frankly, I would *expect* the version in the top example in the question, not the bottom one. If you want to formally define the types of each element, that's usually done in a schema (xsd), not in the payload (xml).